# SSRS Report with related subreport for each record

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

Im just starting out using SSRS and need to make a set of reports for a given query.

I have a query which returns like 100 rows:

```
SELECT name, address, region

FROM tableA
```

I want each of these records to be on their own page. 

I then also need to include another subreport/report on each page which lists the results of another query related to each record at the top of each page.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableB
WHERE region = (whatever the region is of the record at the top of that page)
```

Is there a way for me to do this?

The end result needs to be 100 separate pages which each include: the info from one record from the first query and then the results of the second query, listing all records of people that live in that same region.

Comment: try grouping your parent records in a report then insert subreport within the group section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, will create a table that relates to the query from the first dataset.
Group by id or name. In a column in that table, will put a subreport. 
Thus, for each line he calls a subreport.

Then go to "**Group Properties -> Page Breaks -> and check Between each instance of a group**"

Regarding the issue "*(whatever is the region of the record at the top of page que)*":

Can pass the "region" in parameter, the main report to the subreport.

If you need help let me know.

Comment: I got it so that each page only had one record on it, but now i cant manage to set the one value of the first report to a parameter to be used in a query for the second half of the report.

Comment: I just really need the region field to become a variable that could then be used in the query for the second report.

Comment: Just pass the value from main report to subreport through Properties of SubReport -> Parameters